# Insert List/Array in other List at specific index

Tags: java, arrays, string

I tried many things by now, but can't really solve my problem.
I got a String-List with some Strings in it, and another String-List/Array with some other strings in it. Now I want to insert this second list at a specific position in the first list. Here a little example(Peusdocode with question in it):

```
List<String> list1; //Contains, for example, "Hello", "Keyword", "Bye"
String[] stringarray = new String[]{"Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3"};
for(String s : list1){
  if(s.contains("Keyword"){
    //here i need a method to replace the list item with "keyword" in it with the whole     other list, so that the final list will look like this: "Hello", "Blah1", "Blah2", Blah3", "Bye"
    list1.set(list1.indexOf(s), stringarray); // such a method would be incredible
  }
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Why don't you use directly `list1.contains("Keyword")` instead of a for loop ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking since you're trying to add an String array to a `List<String>`

Comment: *"HERE I NEED.."*  to stop SHOUTING for pity's sake.  Please edit your post, and then later, after my headache has subsided, I might be able to read those comments.

Comment: @ZouZou - OP wants to find an element of the list that contains the keyword as a substring, not one that is (necessarily) equal to the keyword.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes you're right and obviously a for loop is needed. The example was misleading.

Comment: @ZouZou Because the keyword might be hidden in another sentence.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yep, thats exactly what I want.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, I thought it might be better to use caps lock, since it could be easily "over-read", since it's in the code (Sorry for my bad english... I hope you understand.)

Comment: *"I hope you understand."*  What I understand is that you failed to act on my tip to edit something that most people who help around here, detest.  But then, it is no skin off my nose as to whether or not you get an answer.. (shrugs)

Comment: OK - all lower case as opposed to being SHOUTING is considered 'mumbling'.  But hey, close enough.  Down-vote removed.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), you need this method :

```
public boolean addAll(int index,
             Collection<? extends E> c)
```

> Inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this
>   list, starting at the specified position. Shifts the element currently
>   at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right
>   (increases their indices). The new elements will appear in the list in
>   the order that they are returned by the specified collection's
>   iterator.

So I would do something like this :

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "Keyword", "Bye"));
String[] stringarray = new String[]{"Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3"};
int index = list1.indexOf("Keyword"); //get the index of the keyword
if(index != -1){ //if it's different than -1, it means that the list contains the keyword
    list1.remove(index); //remove the keyword from the list
    list1.addAll(index, Arrays.asList(stringarray)); //insert the array in the list at the position where keyword was
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

Output :

```
[Hello, Blah1, Blah2, Blah3, Bye]
```

**EDIT** :

I misread your question but the idea remains the same. if you want to replace all elements by each word that contains the keyword just do :

```
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    if(list1.get(i).contains("Keyword")){
        list1.remove(i); 
        list1.addAll(i, Arrays.asList(stringarray)); 
    }
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

Comment: I rollbacked your post to revision 1, as the Google New Year animation is a bit distracting and unrelated to your answer.

Comment: I think OP wants to replace an element (all elements?) that contains the keyword, _possibly as a substring_. That's different from what you are doing, which is to replace the first element (if any) that is equal to the keyword.

Comment: @TedHopp Oh, you're right. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3"};
    List<String> arrayAsList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
    List<String> original = new ArrayList<>();
    //Populate original

    if(original.contains("Keyword"){
         original.addAll(original.indexOf("Keyword"), arrayAsList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
boolean addAll(int index,Collection<? extends E> c)
```

In [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29) you will find more info.